# Extracted data/text from a webpage is not inserted into mysql db

Tags: php, html, mysql, xpath

I am trying to insert text extracted from a webpage but it not inserted into db. I am using xpath expression to extract data and the data on webpage is within the multiple html para or  list item tags.

here is the code

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "olx";
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ("Error connecting to database");
mysql_select_db($dbname, $conn);
$res1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `item_url` WHERE id=10");
while($r1 = mysql_fetch_array($res1))
{
    $url = $r1['url'];

    $html = file_get_contents($url);       
    $doc = new DOMDocument(); 
    @$doc->loadHTML($html);     
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

    $details = $xpath->evaluate("//div[@id='description-text']/child::div");
    foreach ($details as $detail) {
        $nodes = $detail->childNodes;
        foreach ($nodes as $node) {
        $string = $node->nodeValue;
        $string = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9@.\-]/', ' ', $string); //allow required character
        $string = strip_tags($string); //remove html tags 
        echo $string . '<br>';
        }
    }

  mysql_query("INSERT INTO `test` (`detail`) VALUES ('$string')") or die(mysql_error());
 }
 ?>
```

it displays data in this way

```
Performs skilled technical work in the maintenance, repair, replacement, and installation of air conditioning systems.

Installs, troubleshoots and repairs air conditioning units.

Replaces expansion valves, compressors, motors, coil units and other component parts.

Technicians work in residential homes, schools, hospitals, office buildings, or factories.
```

can't insert this data into db.Is this the issue of xpath nodes.each line is within the

tag on webpage.

below is the html of webpage

```
<div id="description-text">
    <h2 class="title-desc">
    <span>Ad details</span>
    </h2>
    <ul class="item-optionals">
    <li style="background-color: rgb(251, 251, 251);">
    </ul>
  <div style="padding-right: 30px; width: 388px;">
      <p> Performs skilled technical work in the maintenance, repair, replacement, and installation of air conditioning systems.</p>
      <p>Installs, troubleshoots and repairs air conditioning units.</p>

      <p>Replaces expansion valves, compressors, motors, coil units and other component parts.</p>

      <p>Technicians work in residential homes, schools, hospitals, office buildings, or factories.</p>

   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please notice, you'r using `$string = ` inside the loop. so basically you're overwrite it over and over again. in the end you'll have only the last node in that variable.
Add another variable, `$content` and use it like: `$content .= $string` in the end of the loop.

Comment: it shows similar detail for all items.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, the only problem is that you called mysql_query at the end of the loop which processes single nodes of the html page, to solve it it's enough to bring up the `mysql_query` call in the most internal foreach loop.

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "olx";
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ("Error connecting to database");
mysql_select_db($dbname, $conn);
$res1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `item_url` WHERE id=10");
while($r1 = mysql_fetch_array($res1))
{
    $url = $r1['url'];

    $html = file_get_contents($url);       
    $doc = new DOMDocument(); 
    @$doc->loadHTML($html);     
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

    $details = $xpath->evaluate("//div[@id='description-text']/child::div");
    foreach ($details as $detail) {
        $nodes = $detail->childNodes;
        foreach ($nodes as $node) {
        $string = $node->nodeValue;
        $string = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9@.\-]/', ' ', $string); //allow required character
        $string = strip_tags($string); //remove html tags 
        echo $string . '<br>';
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'test' ('detail') VALUES ('$string')") or die(mysql_error());
        }
    }


}
?>
```